# NavigationView: How to click on Drawer Header and make it fancy?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview

i set up a `NavigationView` Drawer successfully and like the ease of implementation a lot. However, i need my header image which is part of the `LinearLayout` which i pass as `app:headerLayout` to be animated when clicked and i was not able to achieve this. I need your help please.

Here is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This DrawerLayout has two children at the root  -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AnimationFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, GameFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, TextSendFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, FriendFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
    //private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout dlDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Find our drawer view
        dlDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        dlDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

       nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    // Setup drawer view
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

    View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nav_header, nvDrawer, false);
    nvDrawer.addHeaderView(headerView);

    /* TODO get the IMAGE and make it clickable */

   headerImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nav_header_image);

    headerImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});
    /*
    headerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    */

    }


    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        /* Logout is a special case which launches a new activity so we separate it. */
        if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_fifth_fragment){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        /* Else we use our Fragment switching mechanism */
        else {
            // Create a new fragment
            Fragment fragment = null;

            Class fragmentClass;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                    fragmentClass = AnimationFragment.class;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                    fragmentClass = GameFragment.class;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                    fragmentClass = TextSendFragment.class;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_fourth_fragment:
                    fragmentClass = FriendFragment.class;
                    break;
                default:
                    fragmentClass = AnimationFragment.class;
            }
            try {
                fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
        }
        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        dlDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dlDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // Make sure this is the method with just `Bundle` as the signature
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        drawerToggle.syncState();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void onFragmentInteraction(String id){
        //you can leave it empty
    }

}
```

Here is my nav_header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nav_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer_pixel_background3"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nav_drawer_cooler"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nav_header_username"
        android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/user_name"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_main_text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/nav_header_username"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:text="@string/user_mail"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_main_text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Crash report:

```
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pymdev.pym/com.example.pymdev.pym.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.pymdev.pym.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139) 
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960) 
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
11-05 11:06:33.101 357-357/com.example.pymdev.pym E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: cant you do @+id/nav_header.setOnclickListener()?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. Can you be more specific? In code or in XML?

Comment: When i set an `onClickListener` on the RelativeLayout, my App crashes instantly with NullPointer Exception. And yes, my `LinearLayout` is clickable. It seems that it behaves different from a normal layout item?

Comment: Please add the crash and the code for the onClickListener

Comment: I added the crash report. It gives me a NullPointerException when i try to set a `OnClickListener` to the Image in the  `nav_header` layout

Answer (score 7):

i found the error which causes the NullPointerException.

```
headerImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nav_header_image);
```

has to be changed to

```
headerImage = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_header_image);
```

Hope it helps someone. I use it in combination with a onClick handler to change the Image in my `NavigationView` Header when clicked.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set your header view in the xml like so `app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"` and then in the code you can access it via `navigationView.getHeaderView(0)`